# tomcat-maven-plugin ignores my <warFile>-def in configuration

Tags: tomcat, maven, deployment, maven-tomcat-plugin

I wanna deploy my project on my tomcat and have one problem. The plugin always assumes I wanna have the standard war-file definition deployed (`{project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war`) and says it can't find it. But I'd like to specify this on my own. This is what the code looks like:

```
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
  <configuration>
<warFile>/path/to/my/war/project.war</warFile>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Is it possible that when the plugin won't find the the specified war it automatically searches for the standard-war-file?